# How to SELECT a record per category in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, select, web-crawler

In a table of articles

```
title varchar(255),
category int(11),
processed enum('yes', 'no'),
... other columns
```

, I want to process rows (`SELECT` a row and then `UPDATE`). However, I need to do this diversely for all categories. Not processing randomly, e.g. all records for a category, but nothing for another.

1. **Basic Case:** process x rows for each category.
2. **Advanced Case:** define a daily limit for each category (in its table). This will be similar to crawlers, as we define how many pages should be crawled for a domain in a given period of time.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * from articles WHERE process='no' LIMIT 1
edit the columns in PHP
UPDATE articles .... WHERE id=xx (id comes from SELECT).
```

Table:

```
id    title    category  process
1     title1   3         no
2     title2   3         no
3     title3   3         no
4     title4   3         no
5     title5   5         no
6     title6   5         no
7     title7   5         no
```

If I run the query regularly by cron, it will process all articles in category 3 then category 5. I want a query to process one from category 3, then one from category 5, and so forth. I want to process from all categories gradually.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what "processing" involves?  If it's just "`SELECT` then `UPDATE`", why not just `UPDATE`?

Comment: Hard to tell what's being asked here, but perhaps you're looking for [`LIMIT`](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)? Or perhaps you just need to make a single `UPDATE` query with a `FROM` clause? Like `UPDATE articles SET ... WHERE processed = 'no' AND category = ' ... '`

Comment: We need more information to help you.

Comment: Thanks folks, I added an example. I thought it is clear by giving the example of crawlers. I want to systematically process all categories together.

Comment: @eggyal, I need this PHP processing, it will edit lots of text; it's indeed a long process.

Comment: Which article within each category should be processed first?  Or does it not matter?

Comment: @eggyal doesn't it matter at all, I just want to process articles from all categories. For example, process a few articles from each category everyday.

Comment: @Ali: OK, lets suppose for a moment that you have a statement that does that. WHen you run this for the 2nd (or 3rd) time, do you expect it know what it had processed the 1st time and now process the 2nd (or 3rd) row for every category? Or is the `processed` column to be used for this?

Comment: @ypercube as I said before, I plan to add a column for daily records of each category (in category table, not articles). I was sharing the technique here to find the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE category =
(SELECT category
FROM Table
WHERE process = 'no'
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY COUNT(category) DESC
LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

..will give you one row with the smallest id for the category with the most rows that haven't been processed. The subbquery returns the category with the most process='no' rows.

If you have lots more 5s than 3s, this will keep giving you 5s until there are more 3s than 5s then it will start alternating with each query (as long as you are marking the row as process = 'yes' each time).

Answer (score 1):

To select `$n` from each category:

```
SET @last := NULL;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT   *,
           @fetch:=IF(category=@last, @fetch-1, $n) x,
           @last :=category
  FROM     articles
  WHERE    process='no'
  ORDER BY category
) t WHERE t.x > 0;
```

To select for each `category` the associated `number` from the `numbers` table:

```
SET @last := NULL;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT   *,
           @fetch:=IF(category=@last, @fetch-1, numbers.number) x,
           @last :=category
  FROM     articles JOIN numbers USING (category)
  WHERE    process='no'
  ORDER BY category
) t WHERE t.x > 0;
```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfc36/3).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the processing that is to be done in PHP is somethign that invloves either user editing or some complex procedure (crawling) that cannot be done by SQL. In that case, you can use this query to get the columns you need from `articles` table.

One article per category:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM 
    category AS c 
  JOIN
    articles AS a 
        ON  a.id = 
            ( SELECT id
              FROM articles AS aa
              WHERE category = c.id
                AND process = 'no'
              ORDER BY whatever
              LIMIT 1
            ) ;
```

and then update:

```
UPDATE
    articles
SET
    process = 'yes'
  , other_column = ...
WHERE
    id = ?              --- one of the ids you have previously 
                        --- selected and processed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Update query of **eggyal** : set variable for @n
`
SET @n    := 3;
SET @last := NULL;

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT   *,
           @fetch:=IF(category=@last, @fetch-1, @n) x,
           @last :=category
  FROM     articles
  WHERE    process='no'
  ORDER BY category
) t WHERE t.x > 0;

//query run
`